# Amqlib channel.checkqueue giving latency

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

I am using channel.checkqueue in node js of amqlib library to check rabbitmq count ,but when traffic gets increase on a machine then channel.checkqueue latency also gets increase.Why it would be happening and how I can improvise the same